# Flexbox Image Layout Columns

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am creating an Image layout using flex box and trying to make it so when the page gets resized the images that have fallen will align with the columns instead of being centered below them. I though maybe putting a `float:left;` on the images would work but nothing happened. What am I doing wrong here? Anything helps, thanks!

```css
/*Fonts*/
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600);
@import url(https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/css/all.css);

/*Body*/
body {
 font-family: "Open Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
 background-color: #fefefe;
 padding-bottom: 3rem;}

/*Profile Picture*/
.profile-picture {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 55px;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;}
.image {
  background-image: url('https://www.dropbox.com/s/8dtg60sbha99x2o/Photo%202018-02-05%2C%209%2026%2043%20AM.jpg?raw=1');}

/*Profile Name*/
.profile-name {
  text-align:center; 
  margin-top:-20px; 
  margin-bottom:35px; 
  font-weight:bold;}

/*User Name*/
.user-name {
  text-align:center; 
  margin-top:-30px; 
  margin-bottom:35px; 
  color:rgba(1,1,1,0.35);}

/*Follow Button*/
.follow-button-position {
  text-align:center;
  margin-bottom:55px;
  margin-top:-10px;}
.follow-button {
  text-align:center;
  padding-top:7.5px;
  padding-bottom:7.5px; 
  padding-left:25px; 
  padding-right:25px;
  border-radius:2px;
  background-color:rgba(1,1,1,0); 
  border-style:solid; 
  border-color:#af985a; 
  border-width:1px;
  color:#af985a;}
.follow-button:hover {
  cursor:pointer;}

/*Posts*/
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
flex-wrap: wrap;}

img {
    max-width:270px;
  height:auto;
padding:15px;}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="profile-picture image">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="profile-name">
  <p>cole gwoz</p> 
</div>

<div class="user-name">
  <p>colegwoz</p>
</div>

<div class="follow-button-position">
  <button class="follow-button">Follow</button>
</div>

<div class="flex-container">
  <div>
<img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/4c05cegbonfqo5k/Photo%202018-03-03%2C%202%2020%2022%20PM.jpg?raw=1"></div>
  
  <div><img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/qzuhelo4lf7eyu0/Photo%202018-01-01%2C%204%2038%2037%20PM.jpg?raw=1"></div>
  
  <div><img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/8dtg60sbha99x2o/Photo%202018-02-05%2C%209%2026%2043%20AM.jpg?raw=1"></div>
  
  <div><img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/qzuhelo4lf7eyu0/Photo%202018-01-01%2C%204%2038%2037%20PM.jpg?raw=1"></div>
  
  <div><img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/qzuhelo4lf7eyu0/Photo%202018-01-01%2C%204%2038%2037%20PM.jpg?raw=1"></div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `justify-content: center;` to `justify-content: flex-start;` and use margin-left from there.

Usually the container will have some padding for that

Comment: I thought that before, but it messes with my content being in the center of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can even use css grid for responsive image layout with much less css code.

```css
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 8px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(150px, 1fr));
    grid-template-rows: repeat(5,minmax(200px,1fr));
}
.container > div > img{
    object-fit: cover;
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
        <div class="container">
           
  <div>
<img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/4c05cegbonfqo5k/Photo%202018-03-03%2C%202%2020%2022%20PM.jpg?raw=1"></div>
  
  <div><img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/qzuhelo4lf7eyu0/Photo%202018-01-01%2C%204%2038%2037%20PM.jpg?raw=1"></div>
  
  <div><img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/8dtg60sbha99x2o/Photo%202018-02-05%2C%209%2026%2043%20AM.jpg?raw=1"></div>
  
  <div><img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/qzuhelo4lf7eyu0/Photo%202018-01-01%2C%204%2038%2037%20PM.jpg?raw=1"></div>
  
  <div><img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/qzuhelo4lf7eyu0/Photo%202018-01-01%2C%204%2038%2037%20PM.jpg?raw=1"></div>
  

        </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add another div .flex-container-wrap and give him the same style as .flex-container but change justify-content: center; into justify-content: flex-start;. Hope this will solve your problem.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
flex-wrap: wrap;}

.flex-container-wrap {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
flex-wrap: wrap;}

img {
    max-width:270px;
  height:auto;
padding:15px;}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-container-wrap">
  <div>
<img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/4c05cegbonfqo5k/Photo%202018-03-03%2C%202%2020%2022%20PM.jpg?raw=1"></div>
  
  <div><img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/qzuhelo4lf7eyu0/Photo%202018-01-01%2C%204%2038%2037%20PM.jpg?raw=1"></div>
  
  <div><img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/8dtg60sbha99x2o/Photo%202018-02-05%2C%209%2026%2043%20AM.jpg?raw=1"></div>
  
  <div><img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/qzuhelo4lf7eyu0/Photo%202018-01-01%2C%204%2038%2037%20PM.jpg?raw=1"></div>
  
  <div><img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/qzuhelo4lf7eyu0/Photo%202018-01-01%2C%204%2038%2037%20PM.jpg?raw=1"></div>
  
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Still messes with the content being in the center of the page

Comment: Did you add another div like I did and use the css properly. You can run my code snippet and make it full page and resize to check.